# Host Java Web App in IIS

Tags: java, azure

I have tried the following links to setup and host a Java web app on our server and can't seem to get it going.

The application is [MyCollab](https://community.mycollab.com/docs/hosting-mycollab-on-your-own-server/installing-mycollab/).

I followed instructions from the following links

1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/
2. http://itmeze.com/2015/08/23/deploying-clojurejava-based-web-app-via-jetty-on-windows-and-iis-step-by-step-guide

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: How is this a **programming** question? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: So, what's the issue you can not solve? Please post it with your key code.

Comment: I did manage to get it hosted on Windows server and viewing it from a web URL. I now have a new problem where the homepage does not load after installation :/

Comment: @Orion Hi,Orion. Have you checked the trace log on KUDU?Have you see any error log in it? Please offer more infomation about your issue.